# How do I programmatically disable the "Use Printer Offline" menu option in the print spooler?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, print-spooler-api

In the print spooler dialog for any installed printer, there is a menu option to use the printer offline. Enabling this option means that all documents will be queued until the said printer comes online.

#### The option I'm talking about:

[image: The option I'm talking about]

I do not want this for my application which interacts with a printer. This is because I need to tell the user (it's a requirement) when the printer is not connected. I'm using the [`GetPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144911(v=vs.85).aspx) function with the [`PRINTER_INFO_2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845(v=vs.85).aspx) structure to check for the `PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_WORK_OFFLINE` attribute.

When I manually disable the aforementioned option, my `GetPrinter` method tells me that the printer is offline when it is not connected and online when it is. When I leave that option enabled, the `GetPrinter` method always tells me that the printer is online (which I understand).

How do I disable the "Use Printer Offline" option programmatically?

Comment: Just wondering if you have read this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160456

Comment: @Cha - The KB article cited answers the question.  Make it an answer so it can be accepted and others can benefit from it.